# how to prevent calling the Rest WebService from Postman?

Tags: java, rest, web-services

i have a webservice that i call it from java Code like the following

```
            URL url = new URL("http://10.10.14.35:7004/rest/resources2/aa/api2/v_12/mywebserv
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");



            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            os.write(JsonObject.getBytes());
            os.flush();
```

i want to secure it in a way if its called anywhere outside this java class (from postman for example ), it must not allow that

Comment: You cannot actually restrict your service that it can be only called through your Java code, what you can do is you can block other IP addresses. 
Or you can use authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about you really need it?

Main idea of web services is to be client side agnostic

What you are thinking about - will be not a service, but just trivial client-server application.

How about standard way of security/authentication over HTTP, using SSL / 2-way SSL etc...

Google about it if you'd like...

P.S.:
- you also can build your own hashing/encryption code on client to makecsome hash value 
- pass it in custom header
- and only server can dectyrpt, recognize and validate it

but... it is almost what Digest authentication is about, and still it will be not a web service anymore...